# It's... time to track

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

### I'm looking for a specific answer.

---

```
  | = A,S,L,C,R,K,V
  / = B,E,U,M,Y,F,P
  \ = D,W,T,G,X,Q,J
  - = O,I,N,Z
 


       

      

   • • • • • • 
    •       •
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
        •  
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
        •   •
   • • • • • •

   • • • • • •
        •    
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
    •   •   •
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
    •      
   • • • • • •

   • • • • • •
    •       •
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
    •       
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
    •   •
   • • • • • •
     
   • • • • • •
    •   •   
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
        •   •
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
            •
   • • • • • •
      
   • • • • • •
        •   
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
    •   •  
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
        •   •
   • • • • • •

   • • • • • •
        •   •
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
    •       •
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
            •
   • • • • • •    

   • • • • • •
    •       
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
        •   •
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
    •       •
   • • • • • •

   • • • • • •
        •   
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
    •      
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
    •   •   •
   • • • • • •

   • • • • • •
            •
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
        •   •
   • • • • • •
   • • • • • •
    •   •    
   • • • • • •
```

**3 2 4 3 1 4 3 1 2**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> **TIC-TAC-TOE**

Method:

> Note that there are two patterns of dots recurring throughout the puzzle:
>
> ```
>  • •         • •
>   •    and
>  • •         • •
> ```

They appear to be

> a cross and a circle when the dots are joined correctly.

This suggests that we are going to

> play 'noughts-and-crosses', aka 'tic-tac-toe'!

So,

> convert each section of 6×6 dots to a tic-tac-toe board and trace the winning row/column or diagonal.

Then considering the data given at the beginning and the end of the puzzle, we can extract the answer.

For example,

> in the first board, we get a `\` and the first number in the string (`3`) says we should take the 3rd letter of the set denoted by `\`, that is **T**.

> [image: answer]

Comment: This looks right but I think you've missed something in the first step. Rot13(Wbva gur qbgf. Gung 6k6 tevq vf gur B'f naq K'f, (jvgu gur K'f arrqvat gur rkgen qbg va gur zvqqyr))

Comment: @fljx thanks. Will update my solution later.

Comment: Well done! This is the correct answer. Just like @fljx says, that was the idea behind the dots